# MySQL updating a Boolean field value based on the duplicated appearance of another filed value of the same row from another table

Tags: mysql, duplicates, mysql-workbench

i have a table (inactive) like:

email (varchar 50), country, active? (2)

and another table (active) like:

email (varchar 50), country

i want to check if any of the addresses in email column at "active" is also in the "inactive" table and if so so it would update the "active?" column to: 0/1 or yes/no.

Comment: Why do you have two tables for this to begin with?

Comment: cause its to separate things for me.

Comment: That makes little sense. You already _have_ the data “separated”, by the value of that active column. One table is all you need here – and all you _should_ use, because then your problem that you’re trying to solve here wouldn’t even exist.

Comment: yeah but im not trying to get rid of the problem im trying to solve it and its not possible for me to change the tables, when working on active data its very hard avoiding inactive data in complex querrys

Comment: A messed-up data model is highly likely to cause you additional problems further down the road. So your best move is to fix this now.

Comment: thanks man i appreciate the advise but im not looking for this solution, can you or someone please help write this query? (its very much like v lookup in excel)

Comment: @Ben If you're so clueless that you couldn't figure this out from Google in two minutes, you should listen to people who understand this stuff. Your judgment about what solution you should want is worthless. He's helping you.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks for the lesson

Answer (score 0):

```
update test1
  inner join test2
  on test1.email = test2.email
  set test1.active = 1
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution using UPDATE LEFT JOIN:

```
UPDATE  inactive i LEFT JOIN active a USING(email)
SET i.`active?` = 1
WHERE a.country IS NOT NULL
```